# Cypress + Typescript: How to use JS methods on return values of type Cypress.Chainable<string>?

Tags: typescript, cypress, return-type, typing

I'm relatively new to Typescript and though I think I understand most of it, what I don't understand is why I can't use standard JS methods on values that have a type of Cypress.Chainable.

For instance:

```
const chainedString: Cypress.Chainable<string> = cy.wrap(" test ")
const trimmed = chainedString.trim()
```

Throws an error like so: `Property 'trim' does not exist on type 'Chainable<string>'`

How would one work with returned, chainable values and use JS methods on them without erring out on typing?

Searching online did not prove very helpful - limited resources for Typescript projects in Cypress

More below...

This is the custom command. Below it is the type definitions

```
Cypress.Commands.add('checkText', (XpathSelector, options?: CheckTextType ) => {
    return cy.xpath(XpathSelector).invoke('text').then(text=>{
      text = text.trim() // remove trailing whitespace

        if(options!=undefined){
            // if options has values provided, run checks
            if(options.matchCase==undefined || options.matchCase==true){
                //* Matching case!
                try {
                    expect(text).to.contain(options.textToAssert)
                } catch (error) {
                    if(options.ignoreError==false || options.ignoreError==undefined){
                      if(options.messageOnFail!=undefined){
                          throw new AssertionError(`${options.messageOnFail}. Error was \n ${error}`)
                      } else if(options.messageOnFail==undefined){
                          throw error
                      }
                    } else {
                      return cy.wrap(false)
                    }
                }      
            } else {
                //* NOT matching case!
                try {
                    expect(Cypress._.toLower(text)).to.contain(Cypress._.toLower(options.textToAssert))
                } catch (error) {
                    if(options.ignoreError==false || options.ignoreError==undefined){
                      if(options.messageOnFail!=undefined){
                          throw new AssertionError(`${options.messageOnFail}. Error was \n ${error}`)
                      } else if(options.messageOnFail==undefined){
                          throw error
                      }
                    } else {
                      return cy.wrap(false)
                    }
                }
                
            }
            return cy.wrap(true);
        }
        return cy.wrap(text)
    })
})
```

Here is the type definition

```
export type CheckTextType = {
  textToAssert:string
  matchCase?:boolean
  ignoreError?:boolean
  messageOnFail?:string
}


declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
/**
       * @description Checks the asserted text against what the element has. Matching case default is *true*.
       * @returns String of text from the element
       * @param {String} XpathSelector The **Xpath** selector to use to grab the element in question.
       * @param {String} textToAssert The string of element's text you want to assert on.
       * @param {Boolean} matchCase Specify false if you want to use lowercase strings. Else, case will be matched
       * @param {Boolean} ignoreError Speficy true if you want to ignore the default error thrown when command assertion fails
       * @param {String} messageOnFail Input a string to include in the output if the command assertion fails
       * @example cy.checkText("//div[contains(@class,'email-address')]", {textToAssert:"example@gmail.com", matchCase:false})
       */
      checkText(XpathSelector:string, {textToAssert, matchCase, ignoreError, messageOnFail}?:CheckTextType):Chainable<Chainable<string> | Chainable<boolean>>
 }
}
```

Comment: I see from your comment that it's a custom command that is failing. Take a look [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-todomvc#custom-commands) for how to create a type entry for your command.

Comment: This [reference](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Using-an-External-Typings-File) also

Comment: Thank you Mike. Yeah I seem to have set up my index.d.ts file correctly with the type definition of the custom command. I edited my question above to include the command itself along with the type definition I've got

Answer (score 4):

The first line should also fail, because you are assigning a string not a Chainable.

It should be wrapped

```js
const chainedString: Cypress.Chainable<string> = cy.wrap(" test ");
```

where Chainable is a wrapper object that implements the Cypress queue.

The reason there's no `.trim()` or any other string method are,

- the generic type of Chainable can be anything (string, number, object)
- the purpose is solely to implement command chains

You can easily work on the unwrapped value using `.then()`

```js
const chainedString: Cypress.Chainable<string> = cy.wrap(" test ")
chainedString
  .then(str => str.trim())  // typescript infers str type from above
  .should('eq', 'test')
```

Comment: Thank you @Mike_G, much appreciated! Apologies for the syntax issue in the first place. 

I have a few custom commands in my Cypress suite, one of which returns a chainable string like so: 

`return cy.wrap(myStringImReturning)` 

Attempting to use this value in a `.then()` with a JS method in Typescript errors out. For instance: 

`cy.myCommand(someVar).then((myStringImReturning)=>{ const trimmed = myStringImReturning.trim() })`

Throws the same error...

Comment: In order to get around this error, I have to put this in the callback instead:
`const trimmed = String(myStringImReturning).trim()`

Answer (score 2):

The return type looks wrong since `@returns String of text from the element`, try this instead

```js
checkText(
  XpathSelector:string, 
  {textToAssert, matchCase, ignoreError, messageOnFail}?:CheckTextType
): Chainable<string | boolean>
```

Would be nice if there was a typescript for typescript which looks at the implementation and auto-suggests the type definition.

Comment: Thanks Grainger, I have multiple scenarios in the logic where I can return a string or boolean, that's why it looks odd. Attempted your fix but type checks got angry. 

I agree, a typescript for typescript in that fashion sounds nice!

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't found a solution to this problem yet, minor as it may seem, I will stick with the workaround. Here is a simplified version of my custom command and the solution I'm going with for now (using a type modifier of `String`):

```
export type CheckTextType = {
  textToAssert:string
  matchCase?:boolean
  ignoreError?:boolean
  messageOnFail?:string
}

  /**
   * @description Checks the asserted text against what the element has. Matching case default is *true*.
   * @returns String of text from the element
   * @param {String} XpathSelector The **Xpath** selector to use to grab the element in question.
   * @param {String} options.textToAssert The string of element's text you want to assert on.
   * @param {Boolean} options.matchCase Specify false if you want to use lowercase strings. Else, case will be matched
   * @param {Boolean} otpions.ignoreError Speficy true if you want to ignore the default error thrown when command assertion fails
   * @param {String} options.messageOnFail Input a string to include in the output if the command assertion fails
   * @example cy.checkText("//div[contains(@class,'email-address')]", {textToAssert:"example@gmail.com", matchCase:false})
   */
  checkText(XpathSelector:string, options?:CheckTextType):Chainable<Chainable<string> | Chainable<boolean>>


Cypress.Commands.add('checkText', (XpathSelector, options?: CheckTextType ) => {
    cy.xpath(XpathSelector).invoke('text').then(text=>{
      return cy.wrap(text)
    })
})
```

Useage:

```
cy.checkText(Selectors.general.language).then(txt=>{
    const trimmed = String(txt).trim()
})
```